# is it possible that an attacker catch a page name from history?

Tags: google, chrome, router, url, dns-rebinding

like if an attacker sets a dns rebinding would he be able to get the router name from the history so he can make his attack more accurate .
[image: the results after typing the router ip in the url bar]

Comment: Are you asking specifically about DNS re-binding attacks?  Or is your question more general, such as "Is it possible for an attacker to determine if a URL is in the browser's history?"

Comment: i think  this "Is it possible for an attacker to determine if a URL is in the browser's history"
and not just determine  ... but get the  cached name of that url just like the photo .
.....
but it would  be a  really hack if it's combined with DNS  re-binding ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've confused a few things.

What kind of attacker?  What access do you mean they have?

DNS only does domain resolution - it deals with turning names into IP addresses, for what's in the URL before the first slash, when it's not an IP address.

What you posted is IP addresses, which shouldn't even touch DNS, other than potential reverse-resolves.

Comment: "What kind of attacker"

does it matter ?

"What access do you mean they have"
 outside of the network

i mean maybe when the victim visits malicious page that runs a code to get the router vendor using a dns rebinding attack 
can a malicious code get the name that is shown before the ip  in the results ?

Comment: yes it matters - your question doesn't make sense since it seems to suppose parts of an attack that isn't possible or doesn't make sense, so its not clear whether you think this is someone with MitM access, someone on your network, someone coming from the internet.
Maybe edit your questions to include bulletpoints of what scenario you're worried about, since I suspect we can help correct some of your bulletpoints - something in your understanding isn't right about how stuff works.

Comment: i am talking about just like the auto fill hack

Comment: ask the question properly, but hyou can just disable autofill if you're worried about that.